# Is there any algorithm to generate all subsets of a given set in O(n^2) time?

Tags: algorithm, set, subset

I am just trying out different algorithms for practice and I came across this problem for which I have to generate all the subsets of a given set of elements (non-duplicate).

the naive solution for this is using bitmasking technique. But that has an exponential time complexity i.e O(2^n). In the worst case scenario, value of n can be upto `100000` so in this scenario O(n^2) solution is not very eddicient.

I am just wondering if there is any other more efficient algorithm which can solve this in ~O(n^2)?

Comment: You mean -- is there a way to generate 2^n things in n^2 steps? Maybe by magic.

Comment: The real question is what you want to do with the 2^n sets. If you really need to output them, it's not possible to spend less than 2^n time obviously. But if you want to compute some aggregation of them, i.e. the find the subset that maximizes/minimizes a certain property, it might be possible

Comment: @NiklasB. Well, I can't tell the whole problem because its from a live contest and I don't want to cheat. Btw, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @user OK that is very fair. If you want you can ask after the contest in case there are no writeups

Comment: @user is this all about this problem? https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: @pkacprzak Yes that's the one.

Comment: I can assure you that you do not need to enumerate all subsets in this case. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to for example print all the subsets or store them explicitly anywhere there is no such algorithm. Notice that there are `2^n` subsets of a set of `n` elements and simply enumerating them requires an `exponential time`.

Answer (score 3):

While there is clearly no polynomial time way to generate all subsets of an `n` element set, some ways of doing so are more efficient than others. In particular, if you use a [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) you can go from 1 subset to another by adding or removing a single element from successive subsets. This would make e.g. brute-force knapsack solutions noticeably more efficient (for e.g. n around 30 or smaller).

Comment: Can you please explain the grey code method please?

Comment: @user It is somewhat involved, but the Wikipedia article I linked to describes an algorithm for generating them. Note that even though for many purposes a Gray code is better than the naïve counting from 0 to 2^n-1 in base 2 method, there is no free lunch and it isn't as easy algorithmically to go from 1 subset to the next. It really depends on what you want to do with the subsets if using a Gray code is worth the extra programming effort.